# What is the function of "に" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, particle-に, giving-and-receiving

> 奴隷の分際で王に敬称で呼んでいただくなど……恐れ多いことです。

The slave asked the king to call him by his first name instead of using his surname + "san", so the king asked him why. Then, the slave answered the above sentence.

I don't understand the function of the particle "に", because it seems to imply that is too much to call a king with honorifics, although with the context, it's exactly the opposite: to call a slave with honorifics. Is "に" linked to "いただく"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the other way around. "王に敬称で呼んでいただくなど……恐れ多いことです。" means it is too much for the king to call him with honorifics. 
The form Aに<てVerb>いただく simply means A is doing the action for the speaker.

Comment: Thank you, John. I just wanted to be sure about that peculiarity.